# How to check whether two java objects are same or not in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I need to compare two java objects in freemarker whether both are same or not. is there any way to check equality of two java objects in freemarker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't such possibility out-of-the-box as of 2.3.19; there probably will be in 2.3.20 or so. You have to write a `TemplateMethodModelEx` to implement this, something like `sameObjects(p1, p2)`. In that, you have to extract the raw object from the parameter `TemplateModel`-s. For that, you have to check if the parameter implements `AdapterTemplateModel` then call `AdapterTemplateModel.getAdaptedObject(Object.class)`. Then you can compare the raw objects with `==`, still in Java, then return `true`/`false`.

**Update:** Since I intend to contribute this to FreeMarker, I did some more research. Using `AdapterTemplateModel` is not entirely correct for this, because it may involves conversions (like Python to Java), and then you lose the identity of the original objects, getting a false negative. Using `WrapperTemplateModel` looks like the solution, but it turns out its implementation for Jython is wrong... So the only solution I see that never gives an incorrect result (but might gives an error because it's impossible to do the comparison) is with `BeanModel`. Here's the concrete implementation:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel;
import freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper;
import freemarker.template.TemplateBooleanModel;
import freemarker.template.TemplateMethodModelEx;
import freemarker.template.TemplateModelException;

/**
 * Checks if two values correspond to the same object. This only works if both
 * arguments are wrapped into {@link BeanModel}-s by the object wrapping
 * facility of FreeMarker, which is usually the case for objects that aren't
 * {@code Collection}-s, {@code Map}-s, {@code String}-s, {@code Number}-s,
 * {@code Date-s}, {@code Boolean}-s, Jython objects, Rhino objects or DOM
 * objects. If you are using pure {@link BeansWrapper} for wrapping, this is the
 * case for all objects. If not all the arguments are {@link BeanModel}-s, or
 * some of them are {@code null}-s, this will throw an exception.
 */
public class IsSameObjectMethodModel implements TemplateMethodModelEx {

    public Object exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {
        if (args.size() != 2) {
            throw new TemplateModelException(
                    "Method expects exactly 2 arguments, but " +
                    args.size() + " was given.");
        }
        return toRawArg("1st", args.get(0)) == toRawArg("2nd", args.get(1)) ?
                TemplateBooleanModel.TRUE : TemplateBooleanModel.FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the original object from the argument.
     * @param argName Used in error messages
     */
    private Object toRawArg(String argName, Object argVal)
    throws TemplateModelException {
        if (argVal == null) throw new TemplateModelException(
                "Method doesn't support null arguments, but the " +
                argName + " argument was null");
        if (argVal instanceof BeanModel) {
            return ((BeanModel) argVal).getWrappedObject(); 
        } else {
            throw new TemplateModelException(
                    "Method only supports arguments that were wrapped by " +
                    "FreeMarker (or something else) so that they extend " +
                    "freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel, but " +
                    "the " + argName + " argument wasn't like that (class: " +
                    argVal.getClass().getName() + "). To avoid this error, " +
                    "avoid comparing objects that are Collection-s, " +
                    "Map-s, String-s, Number-s, Date-s, Boolean-s, Jython " +
                    "objects, Rhino objects or DOM objects.");
        }
    }

}
```

To use this, either put it into the data-model, or, assuming you have some template that you used to import/include, let's say, `utils.ftl`:

```
...
[#assign isSameObject = "com.example.IsSameObjectMethodModel"?new()]
...
```

and then in the templates:

```
[#import "utils.ftl" as u]
...
[#if u.isSameObject(o1, o2)]
  same
[#else]
  different
[/#if]
```